# cannot call googleapis library inside html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, requirejs

I've been trying to call a simple function (`uploadFile(test.txt)`) inside an html but I can not call neither my app.js or googleapis library

node.js gives this eror.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadFile is not defined
Uncaught Error: Script error for "googleapis"
Uncaught Error: Script error for "path"
Uncaught Error: Script error for "fs"
Uncaught Error: Script error for "googleapis/build/src/apis/deploymentmanager"
```

path fs and other libraries are called inside app.js using require.js

like this;

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
});
requirejs(['googleapis', 'path', 'fs', 'googleapis/build/src/apis/deploymentmanager'],
function   (google, path,  fs, deploymentmanager) {
..."rest of the code"...}
```

my index.html file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script data-main="js/app.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script> 
        uploadFile("test.txt")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass to `requirejs` need to be **URLs** to **AMD modules**.

You are passing in the **names** (not URLs) of **CommonJS modules**, most of which are Node.js built-ins.

The `require` function from RequireJS and the `require` function built into Node.js solve *similar* problems but are not remotely compatible.

You cannot use RequireJS to load CommonJS modules. You cannot use modules which depend on Node.js features (like `fs`) in a web browser.

---

If you want to use a Google API in a browser, then use the library that Google provide for accessing it from a browser. Note that Google does not intend some APIs to be used from a browser at all and you will need to use server-side code to access them.

Comment: So what can i do to use my code with a GUI. I want to implement it to html because I want an interactive GUI, not to publish on the web. Is there any way to do it without using html?